# Present custom View Controller in Storyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am trying the following:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    CustomVC *vc = [[CustomVC alloc] init];
    vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"weddingDateViewController"];
    [vc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self vc animated:YES];
```

I have build a view controller in my storyboard and have linked a custom class to it (CustomVC). When I run this code to present the view controller the screen fades to black and I see nothing. However, in my storyboard, if I remove the link to my custom class and run this code it fades in normally and I see the view controller I made in my storyboard.

The trouble is I need that custom class to be used. It's a fresh custom class with no changes made to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to CustomVC.h and remove the loadView method